# Terminal command: conda install spyder (ERROR incompatibilities)

Tags: python, terminal, conda, spyder, environment

I would like to install spyder but I get incompatibilities errors and can't understand which ones they are.

**Here my conda list in my specificly created environment (if needed):**
[image]

**Then, when I enter this specific command:**

```
conda install spyder
```

**I get the following error:**
[image]

Can you help me understand what **"Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions"** means ?

Should I downgrade some packages ? If yes, how do I know which ones ?

I could not find any help online...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see proposed duplicate - it has general advice on understanding the conflict reporting and getting a more precise report (via Mamba). Ping me if you disagree with the closing. I would happily reopen if you think the question is different.

Answer (score 1):

I could find a very "dumb" solution.

If you have dependencies issues. Just create a new environment, install **first** the module(s) that had the issue. Then install the remaining modules that should match the correct version of what was installed first.